# Checkbox checked when edit in php

Tags: php, mysql, checkbox

```
<?php
$repeat_days = "0,1,2";
$repeat_array = explode(",", $repeat_days);
foreach ($repeat_array as $repeat_array1): ?>
    <label class="checkbox-inline">
        <input type="checkbox" name="day[]" value="0">SUN
    </label>
    <label class="checkbox-inline">
        <input type="checkbox" name="day[]" value="1">MON
    </label>
    <label class="checkbox-inline">
        <input type="checkbox" name="day[]" value="2">TUE
    </label>
    <label class="checkbox-inline">
        <input type="checkbox" name="day[]" value="3">WED
    </label>
    <label class="checkbox-inline">
        <input type="checkbox" name="day[]" value="4">THU
    </label>
    <label class="checkbox-inline">
        <input type="checkbox" name="day[]" value="5">FRI
    </label>
    <label class="checkbox-inline">
        <input type="checkbox" name="day[]" value="6">SAT
    </label>
<?php endforeach; ?>
```

I need to check a checkbox automatically when edit in php. Here i entered a value static like 0,1,2. 0->SUN, 1->MON, 2->TUE. In this case if the foreach value is equal to checkbox value, the checkbox automatically checked. How can i solve this friends?

Please guide me

Thanks

Comment: Your code is creating 21 check-boxes. Which of them should be checked?

Answer (score 2):

```
<?php
$repeat_days = "0,1,2";
$repeat_array = explode(",", $repeat_days);

    <label class="checkbox-inline">
        <input type="checkbox" name="day[]" value="0" if(in_arrray('0',$repeat_array)){ echo 'checked';} >SUN
    </label>
    <label class="checkbox-inline">
        <input type="checkbox" name="day[]" value="1" if(in_arrray('1',$repeat_array)){ echo 'checked';} >MON
    </label>
    <label class="checkbox-inline">
        <input type="checkbox" name="day[]" value="2" if(in_arrray('2',$repeat_array)){ echo 'checked';} >TUE
    </label>
    <label class="checkbox-inline">
        <input type="checkbox" name="day[]" value="3" if(in_arrray('3',$repeat_array)){ echo 'checked'; }>WED
    </label>
    <label class="checkbox-inline">
        <input type="checkbox" name="day[]" value="4" if(in_arrray('4',$repeat_array)){ echo 'checked';} >THU
    </label>
    <label class="checkbox-inline">
        <input type="checkbox" name="day[]" value="5" if(in_arrray('5',$repeat_array)){ echo 'checked';} >FRI
    </label>
    <label class="checkbox-inline">
        <input type="checkbox" name="day[]" value="6" if(in_arrray('6',$repeat_array)){ echo 'checked';} >SAT
    </label>
```

Comment: I think you mean `in_array()` (only two r's).

Comment: He is explode the string then it returns an array it will check the value is available or not.

Comment: My point was that your example solution has errors (typos) in it.

Answer (score 1):

```
$days = array("SUN","MON","TUE","WED","THU","FRI","SAT");
$checked = array(0,1,2);


foreach ($days as $key => $day) {
    if (in_array($key, $checked)){
        $status = "checked";
    } else {
        $status = "";
    }

    $checkbox = '
    <label class="checkbox-inline">
        <input type="checkbox" name="day[]" value="'.$key.'" '.$status.'>'.$day.'
    </label>
    ';
    echo $checkbox;
}
```

Comment: Great, thanks for letting me know. Accept the answer when you get the chance.

Answer (score 1):

```
<?php

$days = array('Sun', 'Mon', 'Tue', 'Wed', 'Thu', 'Fri', 'Sat');

$repeat_days = "0,1,2";
$repeat_array = explode(",", $repeat_days);

foreach($days as $index => $day) {
    echo '<label class="checkbox-inline"><input type="checkbox" name="day[]" value="'.$index.'"'.(in_array($index,$repeat_array)? ' checked' :'').'>'.$day.'</label>';
}
```